# Memory Leaks in C++ using Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I'm currently working on a program that is pretty well explained in the comment section at the top. I know that when n = 10, E(4) = 8 and E(6) = 9. However, I'm showing E(4) = 7 and E(6) now tells me k is too large. I'm fairly new to coding, and I could really use some pointers on finding my mistakes (no pun intended).

Edit: I do realize that this program is pretty inefficient. If anyone has some tips on optimization they would be much appreciated as well.

Edit: Solved! I ended up making a 2D vector and made a function to sort it in ascending order. My issue with the primes vector not filling was due to me accidentally passing rads to the findPrimes function.

```
/* This program takes in integers n and k. It fills a vector with prime numbers up to n.
    It then finds all prime numbers that can divide integers 1 to n with no remainder and
    fills a vector with the results and the associated n (i in loop) value. The vector is 
    then sorted and the (k-1)th element (k for user) of the resulting vector is displayed. */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void findPrimes(vector<int>&, int);
bool sortRads(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<int> primes;
    vector< vector<int> > kVec;
    vector<int> rads (2, 0);
    int n;
    int k;
    int radN;

    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter k: ";
    cin >> k;

    findPrimes(primes, n);

    //Fills rads vector with rad(n)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        radN = 1;
        for (int j = 0; ((j < primes.size()) && (j < i)); j++) {
            if (i % primes[j] == 0) {
                radN = radN * primes[j];
            }
        }
        rads[0] = i;
        rads[1] = radN;
        kVec.push_back(rads);
    }

    sort(kVec.begin(), kVec.end(), sortRads);

    //Ensures k is within the bounds of rads vector
    while (k > n) {
        cout << "k value too large. new k: ";
        cin >> k;
    }

    cout << "E(" << k << "): " << kVec[k-1][0] << endl;

    return 0;
}

void findPrimes(vector<int>& primes, int n) {
    bool isPrime;

    primes.push_back(1);
    primes.push_back(2);
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        isPrime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j <= (i/2); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == true) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

bool sortRads(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) {
    if (a[1] == b[1]) {
        return a[0] < b[0];
    }
    else {
        return a[1] < b[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any allocations in your code. `vector` will clean up after itself. As long as `k < primes.size()` and your code actually compiles (the last edit made it syntactically incorrect), I don't see how it would leak memory.

Comment: On sight, there are no memory leaks in your code since you make no allocations.  What you do happen to have are accesses to the vector's and you're not checking if the index is in bounds.  An out-of-bounds index could theoretically cause a memory leak if that access does something to the heap manager.  Things like this: `primes[k] << endl;`  You don't check if `k` is in bounds (you should use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to check things like this).

Comment: I've followed the advice of the other answers and changed the vector that I sort and display from. I also checked to make sure that k was within the bounds of rads. Will this sort remove redundant numbers? I am now being told that k is too large when I know that it should not be. I cannot guarantee that memory leaks were present, but valgrind was showing that they were.

Comment: This is becoming very odd. I have put in some cout's to test things. Even though I explicitly assign primes[0] and primes[1], I am being told that primes.size() = 0. I then tried to display the first 2 elements of primes, and sure enough, I ended up with a seg fault. I'm also getting 14 elements for rads when only 10 should be possible when n = 10. What is going on here? I

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can possibly be causing errors is when you use the k value. It's read in, but you never check if k is bigger than the size of the vector. If it is, then there will be problems because you're trying to access something outside the vector. If you change the program to handle that error where k is bigger than the size of the array, then you shouldn't get any memory errors or invalid reads.

-Ash

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect results may be because at the end of main you're sorting `primes` and printing the kth prime rather than sorting `rads` and printing `rad[k]`.